Odoo 17 odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing error
<record id="contract.res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.config.settings view form inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="25"/>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base_setup.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='contacts_settings']" position="after">
            <h2>Contracts</h2>
            <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container" id="contracts_settings">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 o_setting_box" id="allow_unsigned_contract">
                    <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                        <field name="allow_not_signed_contract"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                        <label for="allow_not_signed_contract" />
                        <div class="text-muted">
                            If switched off, annexes creating is possible for signed contracts only.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

Error messages
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/custom/contract_management_system/views/res_config_settings.xml:4, somewhere inside

what the cuase of this error? please help

Are you sure id="contract.res_config_settings_view_form" is wanted, especially contract.?

Yes, this a module upgraded from v16 and other things done but this one keeping me out.

You were trying to override the xml view defined in module contract, and you xpath to div with id contacts_settings , have you checked this div exist in the parent view i.e the base_setup.res_config_settings_view_form

I think you should fix the name of your view.
res.config.settings view form inherit
try to change the space to dot (.)
ex.
res.config.settings.view.form.inherit
